# Jquery, insert Bootstrap Tabledata... missing data

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-table

I am using Jquery to add rows to the Bootstrap table.
However, after the data is added normally, you can see that it does not apply the Bootstrap plugin effect at all.

Below is the time to add the data.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTwuS.png)

When the existing Bootstrap plugin is applied, the search and sorting tasks are completed. However, if you perform search, sorting, etc. to add the data and then use the functions, the following data will be lost. 
And the added data is about 2,000. Is this not the bootstrap plugin automatically pagenating? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/en7pN.png)

What is the problem ?? I've spent a lot of time searching for it, but there is nothing to help ...

this is my code

```
function drawTable(data){
var textToInsert = '';
var tabledata = []
  $.each(data.msg, function(count, item) {

            textToInsert  += "<tr id='listPacket'><td>#</td>"+
                              "<td>"+item['Timestamp']+
                              "<td>"+item['ID']+"</td>"+
                              "<td>"+item['ID2']+"</td>"+
                              "<td>"+item['DLC']+"</td>"+
                              "<td>"+item['Offset']+"</td>"+
                              "<td>"+"----"+"</td></tr>"
            });
        $('#packetFrame').append(textToInsert);
$("#packetList").scrollTop($("#packetList")[0].scrollHeight);
```

This is I useing Plugin

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>


    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/plugins/jqplot.highlighter.min.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.css">
```

Comment: What specific plugin are you using? Some have api's for adding the data to current instance

Comment: try to destroy and re-initialize your plugin on the table element after you change the rows

Comment: @ztadic91 you say "$('#example').DataTable();" this??

Comment: Read the DataTable documents on how to add a new row to an existing `DataTable` by passing in only the data for that row. If you only insert html the plugin doesn't know anything about it

Comment: @paeh yes, but also call [this](https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy()) or do it as ATcharlietfl mentioned, by using the plugins api methods for adding and removal of items

Comment: @charlietfl oh,  i  read  that!. Now, it can show pagenation, but i got the Error....requested unknown parameter '0' for row2, colum0

Comment: So that depends on the configuration of the data and the configuration of your options in the datatable. Is the plugin initialized using existing html or array data?

Comment: @charlietfl oh! i solved that!  cause DataTable () initialize!!

Comment: Not sure if this is related issue but the Html this JS code generates dynamically is incorrect. Timestamp `td` is enclosing all other `td` tags.

Comment: @paeh that is one way but there are more advanced ways also that don't require rebuilding the whole plugin

Comment: @derloopkat Oh it is wrong keystroke !! Thank you for your discovery.

Comment: @charlietfl What is that way????

Comment: I might have misunderstood what you did now I see your answer

Answer (score 0):

Solved !

we have to initialize DataTable(this First!!)

than, fixed that like this https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add()